# IBOutlet is nil after awakenFromNib but not in awakenFromNib

Tags: ios, swift

I've got the `VideoPlayerTableViewCell` class that looks like this:

```
class VideoPlayerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, VideoEntrySetupBase {

    var videoPlayerEntry: VideoPlayerEntryModel?

    @IBOutlet weak var view: VideoPlayerView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        print("VideoPlayerTableViewCell awakeFromNib")
        //setup()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func setup(withEntry: VideoPlayerEntryModel) {
        videoPlayerEntry = withEntry
        view.vidUrl = (videoPlayerEntry?.vidUrl)!
        view.createAndPlayPlayer()
    }


}
```

The class is paired with a xib that only has one view with the type of `VideoPlayerView`. Now the problem that I've got is that the `view` has some value when I checked it inside the `awakeFromNib` function. But when I tried to call `setup` function from either one of the controller's `viewDidLoad` / `viewDidAppear` / `cellForRowAt` functions, the view always returned nil. Why does this happen? How do I fix this?

Thanks.

PS: I've also tried cleaning up the project but it didn't do anything.

Comment: can add screenshot of your nib file? Did you set the File's Owner as `VideoPlayerTableViewCell` or did you set root view call as `VideoPlayerTableViewCell`?

Comment: can you post the code of how you are calling setup()

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. But actually I think I know why. I was using the Content View of the nib instead of a subview inside the content view. When I moved it inside the content view, it worked fine. Sorry for the false alarm. God, I need a coffee right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the false alarm, guys. But actually I think I know why. I was using the Content View of the nib instead of a subview inside the content view. When I moved it inside the content view, it worked fine. Sorry for the false alarm. This is what you get when you have 2 projects on deadlines, one Android one iOS, and another one Unity 3D project waiting for review. God, I need a coffee right now.